# Change a Button position in time

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the Y position of a Button position in function time.
So, for instance, at time 0: the Button position on the Y axe is 0.
At time 1 second: the Button position on the Y axe is 2.

I can use margin_bottom or margin_top, but I just don't know how to do that.

```
Final chrono = (Chronometer) findViewByID(R.id.Chrono)
long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase();
float y = 1000*(float)timeElapsed;
button1.setY(y);
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.
Tell me if you need more details.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Won't Animtaion fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, i want an animation

Comment: Not related to the code: Axis is the singular of axes on a graph. Axe is the singular of axes swinging at a tree. I think you're onto something here. I will start using "axe" from now on as well because it has a much nicer ring to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Animator`. This would be a simple `Y` axis animation

```
Final chrono = (Chronometer) findViewByID(R.id.Chrono)
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(chrono ,
        "translationY", y);
objectAnimator.setDuration(700); //duration of the animation
objectAnimator.start();
```

Here's a good tutorial to get you started

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html#animations_animator

And the Android docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: Thank you, i will use Animator

Comment: @mortimer_onche. I would consider ticking one of the answers as well, so that the question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

I understand you.

setY() and setX() seems to do nothing :(

Depending on your Layout...

You should need to modify the LayoutParams, i will not asume anything so you can view the whole process.

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
Button b = new Button(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams prms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Width,Heigh);
prms.setMargins(left,up,right,down);  //Here you set your X,Y at left,up
rl.addView(b,prms);
```

With that layout you just need to change the layoutParams of the button and set the margin to where you want to position it.

Of course this is not going to be smooth, if you want interpolation use an Animation.

For the animation use the TranslateAnimation class with lets you specify the the end coordinates based on the relative position of the view (like a += instead of a =)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button1,
            "translationY", here put the value you want animated);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(700); //duration of the animation
    objectAnimator.start();
```

> ```
> public static ObjectAnimator ofFloat (Object target, String propertyName, float... values)
> ```
>
> Added in API level 11
>   Constructs and returns an ObjectAnimator that animates between float values. A single value implies that that value is the one being animated to. Two values imply starting and ending values. More than two values imply a starting value, values to animate through along the way, and an ending value (these values will be distributed evenly across the duration of the animation).
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `target`   The object whose property is to be animated. This object should have a public method on it called setName(), where name is the value of the propertyName parameter.
>
> `propertyName` The name of the property being animated.
>
> `values`    A set of values that the animation will animate between over time.
>
> `Returns`
>   An ObjectAnimator object that is set up to animate between the given values.

[ObjectAnimator Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)